# Dropwizard Environment class unwantedly encodes Jersey Client request body to format other than UTF.

Tags: http, jersey, dropwizard

When a Jersey client is created via the call below I am able to send request to my Mock Server with the request body encoded in a UTF format.

```
Client client = Client.create()
```

I initially thought it was the way i was setting the headers in the WebResource but
I've now isolated the problem to lie someone in Dropwizard's Environment class. If i create my client with the following below then when i post my json its get encoded to a non UTF format.

```
Client client =  new JerseyClientBuilder().using(Environment).build();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try disabling gzip when creating the jersey client:

JerseyClientConfiguration jerseyConfig = new JerseyClientConfiguration();
jerseyConfig.setGzipEnabled(false);

final Client httpClient = new JerseyClientBuilder().using(jerseyConfig).using(environment).build();

This solved the problem for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi I found out a little while back who to solve my problem using the same solution but i did not update this with the answer. I will award you though

Comment: as this is the answer.

Comment: Thanks!  Glad you were able to figure out out.